# Структура вопросов "Книги и другие материалы для обучения"

Tags: обсуждение, учебные-материалы, книги-сообщества

Заметил, что содержимое каноничных вопросов «[Книги и учебные ресурсы по фундаментальным знаниям и навыкам разработчика](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474415/204271)» и «[Книги по теме “Алгоритмы”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/576507/204271)» дублирует друг друга. Не стоит ли его строже разделить или наоборот объединить вопросы?

И было бы неплохо таки сделать общим и причесать [вопрос по базам данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/924356/204271).

Comment: Уже лучше. Но имхо, хорошо бы еще привести примеры пересечений, которые вы нашли.

Comment: В [комментариях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576507/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc%d1%8b#comment762214_576507) под одним из вопросов модераторы не смогли договорится, как я понял. Или тогда еще не все были модераторами :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ пересечение очевидно - в "фундаментальный знаниях" есть раздел "Структуры данных и алгоритмы" и есть отдельный вопрос по алгоритмам. Захотел я сегодня добавить информацию об учебнике и не понял в какой из вопросов его включать.

Comment: Сделал вопрос про литературу по базам данных общим. Подскажите, могу ли я еще чем–то помочь?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky спасибо! Можете поделиться мнением, стоит ли объединить "фундаментальные знания" с "алгоритмами".

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Готово!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд, многое движется от общего к частному: сначала рождается что–то общее, раскрывающее тему в базовых терминах, заем это «что–то» эволюционирует, а наиболее развитые части получают свою узко специализированную «жизнь», раскрывающее отдельные части общего детально.

Если это так, то я бы вынес знания по алгоритмам в отдельный вопрос, оставив в исходном ссылку на него.

Comment: Я создал вопрос но мне пришёл "выговор на словах", хотя по сути [вопрос актуальный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/975214/Книги-и-учебные-ресурсы-по-созданию-ПО-для-дополнительных-устройств-для-компьюте) и ответа на него на сайте нету ((((( (в принципе я бы мог накидать пару книг , но для начала их надо прочесть)